# Stop jsp page from caching

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Okay, so my nocache filter doesn't seem to work. I've read other stackoverflow questions but their answers doesn't seem to work too. I'm using firefox. Tried clearing cache, restarted tomcat. Filter is called too and header shows page is not cached. BUT when I click the back button page still loads..what to do?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    // Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    // Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
    httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
    String method = httpRequest.getMethod();
    String URI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println(method + " request invoked on " + URI);
    chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
}
```

EDIT: I also did try putting < meta> tags, no good..

Comment: Does filter mapping all URLs?

Answer (score -1):

Try Below

```
 httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); //Add this line

 httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);//Remove this line
```

Find detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: I've read that too. Tried changing it to -1. Still no good. Hitting back button just loads the page again.